# I need to extract the first 6 digits and the last 4 digits of numbers in a string and delete leading zeros of the same with a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to delete leading zeros and extract the first 6 digits and the last 4 digits of numbers in a string with regular expression.

I currently have a code that performs the operation I want, but I would like to change it to a regular expression.

//CODE

```
let product1 = {
 number: '00005598001400248980',
 type: 'TC'
 },
 product2 = {
  number: '00000377820202008104',
  type: 'TA'
 };
console.log('Product1: '+merge(product1.number, (product1.type === 'TA') ? {
 minEnd: 5,
 maxInit: 11
} : {
 minEnd: 6,
 maxInit: 12
}));
console.log('Product2: '+merge(product2.number, (product2.type === 'TA') ? {
 minEnd: 5,
 maxInit: 11
} : {
 minEnd: 6,
 maxInit: 12
}));

function merge(number, range) {
 let value = clean(number, 0, range.minEnd) + clean(number, range.maxInit,                 number.length);
 return value;
}

function clean(value, init, end) {
 return value.replace(/^0+/, '').substring(init, end);
}
```

Product1: 5598008980

Product2: 377828104

Comment: If your code works and you seek improvement, you should consider posting the question at [codereview.se]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all leading zeros from numeric string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787090/remove-all-leading-zeros-from-numeric-string)

Comment: 377828104 seems weird unless the first number of the 6 was a `0`

Comment: @epascarello: Yes, because removing leading zeros (and taking the first 6 digits) is a wrong description of what he needs to do.

Comment: `Number(number.substr(4,6) + number.substr(-4))`

Comment: This makes no sense. Your examples do not match the rules which you described.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this regex: `/^0*(\d{6})\d*?(\d{4})$/`

Explanation:

- `^0*` match as many leading zeroes as possible from the beginning of the string - `(\d{6})` capture the following 6 digits
- `\d*?` match as few as possible digits in between
- `(\d{4})$` capture the last four digits at the end of the string

Try it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7Dgt1d/1)

Example:

```js
function extractNumber(numberStr) {
  let match = numberStr.match(/^0*(\d{6})\d*?(\d{4})$/);
  return `${match[1]}${match[2]}`;
}

console.log(extractNumber('00005598001400248980'));
console.log(extractNumber('00000377820202008104'));
```

**EDIT:**
If you need different counts of numbers, you could generate the regex on the fly, e.g.:

```js
function extractNumber(numberStr, firstN = 6, lastN = 4) {
  let regex = new RegExp(`^0*(\\d{${firstN}})\\d*?(\\d{${lastN}})$`);
  let match = numberStr.match(regex);
  return `${match[1]}${match[2]}`;
}

console.log(extractNumber('00005598001400248980'));
console.log(extractNumber('00000377820202008104', 5));
```

Comment: problem is the second number is not correct

Comment: @epascarello you're right, i missed the part that the second number needs only the first 6 digits not 6

Answer (score 1):

If you cast the string `Product1.number` to a number using `+` it will get rid of the starting zeros, then call `.toString()` and use `slice(0,6)`  to get the first 6 digits and `.slice(-4)` to get the last 4 :

```
let product1 = {
    number: "00005598001400248980",
    type: "TC"
  },
  product2 = {
    number: "00000377820202008104",
    type: "TA"
  };

const getDigits = num => {
  const trimmed = (+num).toString();
  return trimmed.slice(0, 6) + trimmed.slice(-4);
};

console.log(getDigits(product1.number));
console.log(getDigits(product2.number));
```

Comment: Second one is going to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let product1 = {
 number: '00005598001400248980',
 type: 'TC'
 },
 product2 = {
  number: '00000377820202008104',
  type: 'TA'
 };

 result1 = product1.number.match(/^(?:0{1,})(\d{6}).*(\d{4})$/)
 result2 = product2.number.match(/^(?:0{1,})(\d{6}).*(\d{4})$/)

 console.log(result1[1]+result1[2])
 console.log(result2[1]+result2[2])

// expected value
//  Product1: 5598008980
// 
// Product2: 377828104
```

Answer (score 1):

After replacing the leading zeros, use the `exec` method with the following expression `/^(\d{6}).*(\d{4})$/` then just concatenate the first and second capturing group from the returned array of `exec` method (the index `1` for the first capturing group and the index `2` for the second one).

```js
const product1 = {
    number: '00005598001400248980',
    type: 'TC'
  },
  product2 = {
    number: '00000377820202008104',
    type: 'TA'
  },
  /**
  * @const clearMerge a function that replaces the leading zeros and returns the first 6 digits and the last 4 digits.
  *   @param n the number to be cleaned and merged.
  **/
  clearMerge = n => {
    /** 
    * 1. replace leading zeros 
    * 2. get the first 6 digits and the last 4 digits
    * 3. concatenate the digits and cast them to an integer (using "+" operator)
    * 4. return the final number
    **/
    const value = +n.replace(/^0+/, ''),
      matched = /^(\d{6}).*(\d{4})$/.exec(value);
    return +(`${matched[1]}${matched[2]}`);
  };

console.log(clearMerge(product1.number)); /** utput: 5598008980 **/
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the codes of the previous answers, I managed to  get the following function:

```js
 let product1 = {
 number: '00005598001400248980',
 type: 'TC'
 },
 product2 = {
  number: '00000377820202008104',
  type: 'TA'
 };
console.log('Product1: '+merge(product1.number, product1.type));
console.log('Product2: '+merge(product2.number, product2.type));

function merge(number, type) {
 return number.replace(type === 'TA' ? /^0*(\d{5})\d*?(\d{4})$/ : /^0*(\d{6})\d*?(\d{4})$/, '$1$2');
}
```